# Email when task assigned

Tags: visual-workflow, tasks, task-notifications

This morning at 6 am EST, one of my flows ran that generates tasks and assigns them to users.  The task generation worked successfully but my users weren't notified that the tasks were assigned to them.  I have tasks generated all the time and the emails are sent without issue.  Thoughts on why this morning would be different?

Comment: Does that specific assigned user have the [setting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335293&type=1&mode=1) "Email me when someone assigns me a task" enabled? I recently had a similar experience with an apex-generated task that was successfully created. Confirmed in email logs it didn't send, but couldn't figure it out. Just one random time.

Comment: I just confirmed in my email log that the emails were sent from Salesforce.  The users are set to receive them.

Comment: If the email logs say they were sent, it'd might be better to dig deeper into the user's inbox or check with whoever manages the email/inbox to see if they got flagged/block as "spam" all of a sudden?